# Retrieve date from double value in NSUserDefaults (Swift)

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsuserdefaults, nsdateformatter

Hi I'm creating an that has two controls: A NSSlider and a NSTextField that update continuously. I added a NSDateFormatter to the NSTextField so that it shows the current value of the slider formatted as a time. The slider has a range of 0 to 86,400 units (so that the user slides the seconds in a range of 24 hours).

I connected my app to the shared user defaults controller so that the value is stored for the user.

The app shows the correct time in the NSTextField, but it always stores the value in seconds. for example, if the user selected 06:32:14 when moving the slider, the system will actually store 23534.2261709793 in the key **startTime**

When the user opens the app again, they will see 06:32:14 as expected.

My problem is when I want to read the variable in my code:

I can read the value as Double:

```
let value = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("startTimeValue") as? Double
```

This works fine, if I try to cast it as NSDate it won't work (the value will be set to nil). So I thought that using a NSDateFormatter in code could work (as this is the way interface builder does the work for the user to see the date):

```
 let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
 dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
 let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString((value?.description)!)
```

In the previous code I created the date formatter, then set the date style to nothing (I only want to do the time), and the time style to short. But giving the value.description ("23534.2261709793") still won't work. date will still be nil.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double that you are storing / getting from NSUserDefaults is the time interval from Thursday 1st January 1970. So you need to feed that time interval into the NSDate constructor so that it can construct the date for you.

```
let value = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("startTimeValue") as? Double
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: value)
```

Comment: Not a problem, glad i could help